# SPFx - PnP Js : Setting value of a custom user profile property

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, user-profile-property, pnp

I am working on building a webpart using SPFx. I need to access userprofile service to set value to a custom user profile property.

I am using PnP Js to achieve this. I found [here](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/de81239150dc6ad411c553da9551e57c7b5a735f/packages/sp/src/userprofiles.ts) that there is a method named
"setMultiValuedProfileProperty" which supposedly should allow to set values. However i could not find any example how to use this method. I tried to use it but getting below exception

> `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is the code snippet for reference.

```
let propValues:string[]=["test"];
  propValues.push("this is a test");
  let userProfQuery:pnp.UserProfileQuery = new pnp.UserProfileQuery("https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/sites/publish");
  userProfQuery.setMultiValuedProfileProperty("i:0#.f|membership|userName@contoso.onmicrosoft.com","MyProperty",propValues).then(
    function(result){
      console.log(result);
    }
  ).catch(function(error) {  
    console.log("Error: " + error);  
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use it as in the below mentioned snippet:

```
let propValues:string[]=["test"];

pnp.sp.profiles.setMultiValuedProfileProperty
("i:0#.f|membership|userName@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", 'MyProperty', propValues).then(
    function(result){
      console.log(result);
    }
  ).catch(function(error) {  
    console.log("Error: " + error);  
});
```

Comment: i am getting below error after using the code snippet you provided:
ProcessHttpClientResponseException: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [500]

Comment: Update : Thanks a lot @Gautam the snippet you provided worked (there was a silly mistake from my end which was causing the error)